# Should we try to disambiguate [dash]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag is officially for the dash shell (judging by the wiki), but a good portion of the questions with the tag clearly are about the character, and not just [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193307/how-to-get-latex-to-hyphenate-a-word-that-contains-a-dash) (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400776/mysql-how-to-order-by-dash), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433736/asp-net-mvc-4-allow-dashes-hypens-in-urls), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384202/strange-behavior-of-preg-match-for-dashes-and-underscores), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379928/is-there-a-category-or-name-for-characters-like-smart-quotes-and-that-dash-that), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090051/c-sharp-random-method-causes-hidden-dash)).

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634622/number-of-segments-in-a-dash-mpd) doesn't appear to be about either; maybe it should be tagged [dash-media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash-media)?

There are also some about [dashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813146/how-to-set-dashed-border-for-uitextview-uitextfield-on-iphone) [borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717873/why-are-border-colors-inverted-when-a-background-gradient-is-applied).

Should we make a new [dash-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash-shell) for the shell, and use [dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash) for the character?  I know it's not symmetric with [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csh), etc., but I think there are legitimate questions about dashes, and more people think of the character when they see "dash" than they think of the shell, I'll bet.  (I actually hadn't heard of the dash shell until I noticed someone trying to systematically detag [dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash) questions that were about dashes.)

Or, should the shell keep its tag and we retag questions about dashes as [dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dashes)?  Precedent: [underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores) (to avoid collision with Underscore.js); counterexample: [apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apostrophe); ambiguous: all the various tags involving quotes or quotation marks (these are almost all plural in construction, but that makes sense because the punctuation is also usually paired... except when it's not, like [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quote) for Lisp, yet *that* tag is also occasionally used for just [regular single-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744315/single-quote-escape-in-javascript-function-parameters) (i.e. apostrophes).

Or perhaps try to retag all questions about the dash character to [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen)? Pros: the tag already exists and has less chance to be mistaken for something else.  Cons: the asker may simply never use the term "hyphen", and really just think of that character as the dash, so all the verbiage in the title and the question body will only mention "dash", and it will never occur to them to use a different tag.

Or just leave it, and let readers sift through the two dominant meanings of [dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash) on their own?

Comment: I hope that the hyphen topics stay one way or another. I only learned about 'n' and 'm' type hyphens yesterday. Because I was forced to use MS Word to document my code, and when I copy-pasted it to verify I'd done it properly it wouldn't work. Because MS Word auto-corrects hyphens into another type than what most parsers use. Not that I used SO to figure it out but Im sure I would have if it'd confused me for much longer. (I had copy-pasted from word into notepad to double check..working line vs non-working looked identical.)

Comment: @BSAFH: It's probably beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, but technically there is no such thing as an "en-hyphen" or "em-hyphen". You're thinking of true (English) dashes. In computing, we tend to lump together hyphen, dash, and minus sign, but they are really very different things, both visually (when properly typeset) and semantically.

Comment: There is another "dash" in use now: [Plotly Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/).

Answer (score 7):

Just remove the tag from questions that aren't about the shell.

"dash" in the sense of the character is not a useful tag in a taxonomy of programming questions.  We aren't a typography site, and questions about programmatic layout can simply be tagged as [typography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typography).  Questions about auto-correct (insertion of typographic dashes when the hyphen key is pressed) or sorting strings containing dashes could be tagged along the lines of natural language processing, I suspect the [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) tag applies to them, insofar as they are programming related.  Your example is sufficiently tagged as [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation).  Orthography questions probably belong on a linguistics sister site.

IMO [apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apostrophe) needs to be burninated as well.

Dashed lines and borders don't need their own tag either, [tagging with the graphics API is best](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12786363/103167).  I would argue that even [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line) isn't needed for those.

Comment: Questions about dash characters are not all about hyphenation, though. See further examples in my edit.

Comment: @JohnY: Still not tag-worthy.

Comment: I take it you would prefer to get rid of all the quotation-mark-related tags as well?

Comment: @JohnY: There are interesting questions which are actually about *quoting*, but no quotation marks themselves don't need a tag.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we should disambiguate the tag, by creating a `dash-shell` tag.

I've completed this change now:

- I cleaned up the tag by retagging posts that were not about the Dash shell, so posts tagged with `dash` really were *only* about the shell.
- I created the [dash-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash-shell) tag, and copied across the `dash` tag wiki excerpt and tag wiki.
- I set the default syntax highlighting language to `lang-sh`
- I merged the `dash` tag into `dash-shell`, with no synonym. This *replaces* the tag on all posts, and the old `dash` tag was deleted.
- I re-created [dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash), then merged this tag into [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen), this time creating a synonym.

so when you type `dash` now, `hyphen` shows up, and so do other options containing the name:

[image: tag widget shows <code>hyphen</code> when you type <code>dash</code>, and shows other completions including <code>plotly-dash</code> and <code>mpeg-dash</code>]

Currently, `dash-shell` is not listed in there because with only 135 tags, it is a niche tag. Type `dash-s` or `dashs` and it'll appear.

---

I've been cleaning up the tag, after someone pointed out that the tag was [being used for the Plotly Dash framework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381375), and the number of incorrect applications  of the tag far outstripped the correct use. There are now around 135 posts left that are actually about the dash shell.

I cleaned up a large quantity of posts that should instead have used

- [plotly-dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly-dash) for the Plotly framework
- [mpeg-dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpeg-dash) for the MPEG streaming format
- [dash.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash.js) for the JavaScript library to play the MPEG streaming format
- [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) for questions about inserting dashes (hyphens) into words, programmatically.
- [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) for questions that deal with other uses of the dash character (sparingly, where it made sense).

and I removed the tag where someone was just asking about an individual dash character in a command or menu option, or a `dash` option in an API, or about dashed lines in graphs or drawing applications or CSS properties. Or the question was asking about the [OS X documentation application](https://kapeli.com/dash) or the [cryptocurrency](https://www.dash.org/), neither of which have enough posts on the site to warrant a tag at this point.

The tag is trivially easily confused for any of the above, and renaming it to `dash-shell` would make it much easier for experts to trust that the tag can be followed to find questions about the shell.

I also propose we then make `dash` a synonym of [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen), in case people want to continue to use it for the various other concepts that have better tags. Typing in `dash` into the tags editor will then at least give them a clear indication that they are probably looking for a different option.

Comment: Suggesting [tag:dash-character] as synonym to [tag:hyphen], too, because people _will_ search it by this name.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I'm not so sure `dash-character` is useful, when `dash` already directs to `hyphen`. If the tag were to appear in future, we can always make it a synonym *then*.

Comment: @Magnetron: I don't really have the time or inclination at the moment. All I did here was clean up the remaining posts at the time.