# What should we do about the quite wide use of [dash] for the Python visualisation framework?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [dash] is in quite a few questions used for [Dash by Plotly](https://dash.plot.ly/). Examples are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102779/plotly-dash-multiple-filters), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999681/using-flask-with-sqlalchemy-and-dash), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145472/plotting-side-by-side-stacked-bar-charts-in-plotly-from-a-dataframe).

My impression is that lately more and more people use [dash] for the visualisation framework and fewer people for the minimalistic shell.

What should we do?

PS: A question which appears to be similar is *[Should we try to disambiguate [dash]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266468/should-we-try-to-disambiguate-dash)*, but that one is about the shell vs. the hyphen character, so in fact it is quite different from the question here.

Comment: Well, Python Dash is another reason to disambiguate the tag, so this *is* a duplicate.

Comment: And I see there is a [tag:plotly-dash]. Just edit the posts to replace [tag:dash] with [tag:plotly-dash].

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your 2nd comment makes truly sense, thanks. But wouldn't this comment be a perfect *answer* to the question? You cannot deduct this from the answers to the other question (about dash and hypen). So I think this answer *here* would be much better than a duplication mark.

Comment: Not sure why that would be, the tag still needs to just be removed from posts that are not about the Dash shell. I've done so now for the Plotly Dash questions.

Comment: The wrong tagging of plotly-dash questions with [dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash) will happen again, and if somebody asks themselves the same question as I did he/she will be guide to the other question where there is no help  to *add* the new tag [plotly-dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly-dash). - If you don't want to put this in an answer here, I'm happy to do so - if you release the duplicate mark.

Comment: The problem with the tag goes well beyond Plotly Dash being mistagged, just stating you can re-tag them is not going to fix those problems. Which is why I've already answered on the other post, with a proposal to completely *remove* the `dash` tag.

Comment: I see! Now that I read your *new* answer to the other question the duplicate marking makes somewhat sense. Thanks for the explanation.