# Could we finally please remove [hyphen] as a synonym for [dash]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

This issue has been raised on a few occasions already with valuable discussions to follow:

[Should we try to disambiguate [dash]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266468/should-we-try-to-disambiguate-dash/381434#381434)

[Let's dash the [hyphen] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408394/lets-dash-the-hyphen-tag#comment848853_408394)

Still, I would argue that more action should be taken since `dash` and `hyphen` are still considered [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hyphen/synonyms):

---

[image]

---

In my opinion, the only correct synonym for [dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash) would be [plotly-dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly-dash) ([official website](https://plotly.com/dash/)). Still, the best would probably be to have no synonyms here at all.

I have no affiliation to these products other than having answered a bunch of [plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly) and [plotly-dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly-dash) questions.

Comment: I would actually challenge the need for either tag instead. Characters are not on-topic for SO, and `dash` might be quite ambiguous in terms of technology names (we have [`dash-shell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash-shell), I don’t know if there are other tags for similarly named technologies, but [WikiPedia has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash_(disambiguation)#Computing), and I also found a programmable robot and an API documentation tool for MacOS named Dash) and the name is likely to be used for other things in the future.

Comment: Issues in rendering characters and with character encodings, along with the use of certain characters as operators in programming languages are all on topic for SO. That said, the action taken for [Should we try to disambiguate \[dash\]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266468/215552) was to create the synonym of [dash] to [hyphen], so I wouldn't say no action was taken. You just disagree with the action taken.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You're right! Particularly if we only consider the first post. In the second post there's a suggestion to burninate the `hyphen` tag. So I'm thinking more along those lines. Or at least not have `hyphen` as a synonym for `dash`.

Comment: I'd argue that dash and hyphen do make sense as synonyms as in punctuation, a dash is just a long hyphen: https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zvwwxnb/articles/zg8gbk7

Beginners likely wouldn't be aware that dash is also the accepted name for about half a dozen other things in computing.

Comment: Further thought maybe we should have a `dash-punctuation` tag that's a synonym for `hyphen` instead of the maddeningly-vague `dash`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey issues with character rendering should be tagged with something like `[character-rendering]`, not with a tag describing the character. Do you really think, it would be useful to have 1,112,064 distinct tags, one for each code point?

Comment: @Holger Obviously not, and that was nowhere near the implication of my comment. But there are certain characters that cause specific and common issues. The non-breaking space character, for instance, [causes confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55355770/215552) on a regular basis. I’m not against burninating [hyphen] or [dash]. I’m just asking that we not go hyperbolic in our reasoning and start tossing babies out.

Comment: ‘the only correct synonym for [tag:dash] would be [tag:plotly-dash]’ — what about Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP?

Comment: @user3840170 That's my *opinon*. My *suggestion* or *request* is to drop `hyphen` as a synonym.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Unless it was recently changed, the tag in your link is `[non-breaking-characters]`, not `[non-breaking-space]`.

Comment: You mean to say "Should we dash out [dash]?, like this: d̶a̶s̶h̶"?

Comment: Hyphens (‐ and -) and dashes (–, —, ‒ and ―) are not the same. They’re distinct characters that both just happen to be horizontal lines. If ‘dash’ is a synonym of ‘hyphen’, then ‘I’, ‘l’, ‘1’ and ‘|’ are synonymous as well.

Comment: The tag should really be called `[hyphen-minus]` because that's what the character is called in Unicode.

Comment: If it's a question about encoding, then it should be sufficient to tag it with the related encoding and programming language.  Tags for specific characters is noise.  Who would monitor all questions related to hyphens?  When would someone be an expert on the hyphen?  Are we going to have an "i" tag for questions related to Turkish handling of i's without a dot?  No, you would tag it as being a culture conversion issue.  Where do we draw the line before we have a tag for every alphanumeric and other character?  Tags don't have to fully describe every minutia of a question.